# How to figure out model.getName() is pointing to what in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have just declared

```
allfamdatabaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(email).child("FAMILY_MEMBER");
```

so model.getName() denotes what and how?

I have written code but confused about that how to read NAME,and other details

**MAIN TASK=HOW TO READ AND DISPLAY All childrens inside a particular user IN LIST INSIDE RECYCLER VIEW under FAMILY MEMBER**

FirebaseDatabase=> Users=>User1=>Aadhaar=>Name
Two variable Name, Aadhaar= Every Node eg "111111111" or "222222222"

I am bit new to firebase.
I have registered user

I have added a recycler view in activity_main file

Database looks:

```
{
  "Users" : {
    "gptshubham595" : {
      "FAMILY_MEMBER" : {
        "111111111" : {
          "AGE" : "19",
          "DISTRICT" : "ABC",
          "DOB" : "2008-11-16",
          "ELIGIBLE" : "YES",
          "GENDER" : "Male",
          "MOBILE" : "0123456789",
          "NAME" : "ABC",
          "PIN" : "826001",
          "STATE" : "ABC"
        },{
        "2222222222" : {
          "AGE" : "19",
          "DISTRICT" : "ABC",
          "DOB" : "2008-11-16",
          "ELIGIBLE" : "YES",
          "GENDER" : "Male",
          "MOBILE" : "0123456789",
          "NAME" : "ABC",
          "PIN" : "826001",
          "STATE" : "ABC"
        }
      },
      "MOBILE" : "0123456789",
      "TOTAL_FAMILY_MEMBER" : "1"
    }
  }
}
```

Then added a allfamily class

```
public class allfamily {
    public  String name,aadhaar;
public allfamily(){

}

    public allfamily(String name, String aadhaar, String dob, String eligible) {
        this.name = name;
        this.aadhaar = aadhaar;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAadhaar() {
        return aadhaar;
    }

    public void setAadhaar(String aadhaar) {
        this.aadhaar = aadhaar;
    }

   }
```

Then added this in mainactivity:

```
 allfamilylist=(RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        allfamilylist.setHasFixedSize(true);
        allfamilylist.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        allfamdatabaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(email).child("FAMILY_MEMBER");
        allfamdatabaseReference.keepSynced(true);


   @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<allfamily, Allfamilyviewholder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<allfamily, Allfamilyviewholder>(
                allfamily.class,R.layout.activity_fam,Allfamilyviewholder.class,allfamdatabaseReference
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(Allfamilyviewholder viewHolder,final allfamily model, final int position) {
                viewHolder.setName(model.getName());
                viewHolder.setAadhaar(model.getAadhaar());
            }
        };
        allfamilylist.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }
    public static class Allfamilyviewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        View mview;

        public Allfamilyviewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mview=itemView;
        }
        public void setName(String famname){
              TextView nameview = (TextView) mview.findViewById(R.id.famname);
                nameview.setText(famname);
        }
        public void setAadhaar(String aadhaar) {
            TextView aadhaarview = (TextView) mview.findViewById(R.id.aadhaar);
            aadhaarview.setText(aadhaar);
        }
    }
```